# Facebook authentication using php sdk and Yii framework

Tags: yii, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a facebook app using the Yii framework and want to use php sdk for authentication and other graph api calls. Though i have a tested script for authentication which works perfectly, i am not being able to implement it properly with my Yii framework generated files.

Right now i am making a **FacebookHelper** class in *components* with the whole authentication code in a

```
    public function authenticator()
```

(have included facebook.php just before this function starts as well as imported using

```
'application.lib.*'
```

where the lib directory under protected is where my php sdk situated)

and the main controller which is the **SiteController** contains the following code for calling it.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
$fbhelper = new FacebookHelper();
$value=$fbhelper->authenticator();
if($value==0){
      die("It works");
    }
    $this->render('index');
}
```

The application calls the login url using the

```
$facebook->getLoginUrl()
```

but facebook displays a msg that some error occured.

What am i doing wrong.

As i am new to the MVC model and Yii framework i am a little lost about how should i go about it, so it will be very much appreciated if you can also explain your answer(i.e. if there is some concept regarding the MVC architecture in it). Thankyou!

Comment: Do you have any more information about the "some error occurred"? Also it might help you (and potential answerers) if you added some calls to `Yii::trace(CVarDumper::Dump($variable_of_interest))`, assuming you have an error log manager configured in `config/main.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following extension for facebook login using PHP-SDK and its working fine..

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Its specific with yii framework..

Comment: You say it's specific to Yii but the link you present is for the facebook php sdk. The link is outdated too: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Comment: This has been depecrated, the new link is at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4